# Disk size is incorrect

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a disk that is 200 GB, but when I mount the device on my VM, I only see 50gb.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am new to Google cloud.

On a separate note, earlier I saw deletion of  a directory taking exceptionally long time on a VM that I created in us-central1-a.  Are there  any scheduled or unscheduled  maintenance outages that may have impact on the performance of this VM?

Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to mount the disk by ID, try mounting the one that has PART1 in it's name. If a region will go for maintenance, Google will notify almost 3 months before, and if you choose to migrate your instance if a maintenance occurs, your instance won't be terminated.

Answer (score 1):

if you created the disk from an existing image you need to repartition it to use the full disk as described at [1].

Ciao
Paolo

Link:
[1] - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd